# riptscope of a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

I have following AJAX.

And what I need to do is to use the variable `tax_rate` outside of `$.ajax` call. My ajax call is working properly since the variable `tax_rate` shows proper value in [1], but the variable becomes useless in [2].

Am I doing something wrong with variable scope?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(document).on('blur','#form',function() {

        var subsum = 0;
        var tax_rate = 0;
        var tax_amount = 0;

        $('.form-row').each(function() {

            // calculate sums and totals per each form-row
            subsum = Number( $(this).find('.unit').val() * $(this).find('.price').val() ).toFixed(2);
            $(this).find('.subsum').empty().val(subsum);

            // calculate tax amount
            var tax_id= $(this).find('.tax_code').val();
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

            // call ajax to retrieve the tax rate
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                data:' action=get_tax_rate_by_id&tax_id='+tax_id,
                type:'GET',
                success:function(results) {
                    tax_rate = results;
                    alert( tax_rate ); // [1] Obviously, this one properly alerts tax rate.             
                }
            });

            alert( tax_rate ); // [2] This one always alerts 0.

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: _AJAX_ stands for __Asynchronous__ which means _not existing or occurring at the same time._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your ajax call synchronously because the alert will get executed before completing your ajax request as JavaScript run asynchronously. Although it will make your code a little slow but you will be able to return tax_rate outside of ajax. You can use

```
async:false
```

in your ajax options to do that.

Comment: So the chances are that [2] gets executed even before the ajax call is completed? I see. Thank you. Your suggestion to make it synchronous works, but the code became too slow. Any other advice?

Comment: That I've mentioned in the answer. Your code becomes slow in case of synchronous ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
            success:function(results) {
                return tax_rate = results;                           
            }
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work.